# Why is npm semver logic for carrat ranges different for v0.x.x

Tags: npm, version, semantic-versioning

I stumbled upon this quandary today regarding the semantic versioning and [caret range](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004) logic of npm.

My understanding was that the caret(`^`) would always pull in the latest minor and/or patch version. Which for versions with a major version of zero (`0.x.x`) that is actually ***NOT*** the case.

npm's [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004) show the following caret range example converted to an explicit range ...

```
^1.2.3 := >=1.2.3 <2.0.0
```

Which makes sense but if now the major version is zero like such...

```
^0.2.3 := >=0.2.3 <0.3.0
```

Notice it would only pull in the latest patch not the latest minor, which seems to be counterintuitive because then that would mean...

```
^0.2.3 := ~0.2.3 := >=0.2.3 <0.3.0
```

If you know the reasoning behind this I would greatly appreciate the enlightenment!

> If you are like me, bewildered by this realization, it's true, just have a look for yourself with this [semver calculator](https://semver.npmjs.com/).

Comment: In 1st sentence of 1st para [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004) the parts to fully grok are:: **1.** _"Allows changes that do not modify the left-most non-zero digit"_. and **2.** _"allows patch and minor updates for versions `1.0.0` and above"_ So given `^0.2.3 := >=0.2.3 <0.3.0` that adheres to points **1** & **2**, i.e. a version `>0.3.0` would change the left-most non-0 digit (point **1**) and `0.2.3` is not `>1.0.0` (point **2**) . For reasoning read 2nd para: _"Many authors treat a 0.x version as if the x were the major “breaking-change” indicator."_